# Batch save all open files?

Tags: batch-file, save

Is it possible to make a batch file save all open documents/things that can be saved? When I search it up on Google all it gives me is "How to save a batch of Photoshop", just if anyone knew :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That completely depends on the program.  But, generally, no.

Comment: Well, it is pretty global to use Ctrl+s for saving, can a batch do that maybe...? It would be files like word and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming two things - unsaved files set the application title (with they are opened) asterisk at the front. Mass save combination is `Ctrl-Shft-S`. Then you can use [`sendKeys.bat`](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) like this:

```
call sendkeys.bat "*" "^+S"
```

Comment: And that would work like, if servral files are open and, even though they're not in focus/marked..? I am basically trying to save everything before my AutomaticShutdown Batch goes of - but it isn't *that* important I guess.

I am open for .vbs script ideas too, but I am honestly very bad at it, so if, and I would appriciate it :)

Comment: @iversen you can execute this few times depending on the applications titles and on the specific keys combinations.I don'g think there's elegant way to do this.